# Shell script doesn't execute from cron job

Tags: linux, shell, cron, jobs

shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
services=( httpd named proftpd mysqld dovecot postfix webmin)

for service in ${services[@]}
do

if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $service > /dev/null
then
    echo "$service service running, everything is fine"     
else
    echo "$service is not running"
    service $service start
fi

done
```

file executable, running from root user

command:

```
bash /etc/mycron/checkServices.sh
```

tried sh and just `/etc/mycron/checkServices.sh`

doesn't run

Comment: Did you set a schedule for the cron job? Post the full crontab comm

Comment: Make the second line "printenv > /tmp/crontest" and tell us what UID the file is and what your PATH is.

Comment: @Seth is right.  cron jobs run with a very limited environment.  "service" command might be under /sbin or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
services=( httpd named proftpd mysqld dovecot postfix webmin)

for service in ${services[@]}; do
    if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $service > /dev/null; then
        echo "$service service running, everything is fine";
    else
        echo "$service is not running";
        service $service start;
    fi;
done;
```

Works fine here...  maybe you want to add after `#!/bin/sh` `PATH="/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/opt/usr/bin:/opt/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin"`

You could also do `chmod 775 /etc/mycron/checkServices.sh` to make it executable, which is needed for cron. Then you would also not need to call `bash /etc/mycron/checkServices.sh` and can just call `/etc/mycron/checkServices.sh` the `#!/bin/sh` tells the executable loader to load the file with `/bin/sh` if you invoke `bash /etc/mycron/checkServices.sh` you will start bash which on his turn would start `/bin/sh` to finally execute your script.

Since the for loop in bash / sh uses the IFS variable (`$IFS`) as delimiter, you could also make the line `services=(httpd named proftpd mysqld dovecot postfix webmin)` as `services="httpd named proftpd mysqld dovecot postfix webmin"` since this is more general

Comment: @lesyk In response to your edit suggestion: Please comment here, and say way **more** than "doesn't work".

Answer (score 1):

Just as a general diagnostic process, it's sensible to insert trace statements into the script such as:

- echo "Starting..."
- echo "Checking for running service '$service'..."
- which/whereis service
- echo "Service has been started."
- temporarily remove the `> /dev/null` for `ps`.

Then execute under cron with stdout and stderr redirected to a log file.

That allows you to identify the exact line that's failing.  As others have said, it looks likely to be the "service" or "$service" commands aren't found because the PATH isn't set to include them.  You do realise "service" itself is being sought as an external command that presumably launched $service in turn?  Also keep an eye on root's mail, as cron sometimes sends error reports via mail.