# Starting a service (upstart) from a shell script, from a cron job

Tags: linux, shell, cron, centos, upstart

I'm trying to use a cron job to call a healthcheck script I've written to check the status of a web app (api) I've written (a url call doesn't suffice to test full functionality, hence the custom healthcheck). The healthcheck app has several endpoints which are called from a shell script (see below), and this script restarts the bigger web app we are checking. Naturally, I'm having trouble.

How it works:
1) cron job runs every 60s
2) healthcheck script is run by cron job
3) healthcheck script checks url, if url returns non-200 response, it stops and start a service

What works:
1) I can run the script (healthcheck.sh) as the ec2-user
2) I can run the script as root
3) The cron job calls the script and it runs, but it doesn't stop/start the service (I can see this by watching /tmp/crontest.txt and ps aux).

It totally seems like a permissions issue or some very basic linux thing that I'm not aware of.

---

The log when I run as root or ec2-user (/tmp/crontest.txt):

```
Fri Nov 23 00:28:54 UTC 2012
healthcheck.sh: api not running, restarting service!
api start/running, process 1939 <--- it restarts the service properly!
```

The log when the cron job runs:

```
Fri Nov 23 00:27:01 UTC 2012
healthcheck.sh: api not running, restarting service! <--- no restart
```

Cron file (in /etc/cron.d):

```
# Call the healthcheck every 60s
* * * * * root /srv/checkout/healthcheck/healthcheck.sh >> /tmp/crontest.txt
```

Upstart script (/etc/init/healthcheck.conf)- this is for the healthcheck app, which provides endpoints which we call from the shell script healthcheck.sh:

```
#/etc/init/healthcheck.conf
description "healthcheck"
author "me"

env USER=ec2-user

start on started network
stop on stopping network

script
    # We run our process as a non-root user
    # Upstart user guide, 11.43.2 (http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#run-a-job-as-a-different-user)
    exec su -s /bin/sh -c "NODE_ENV=production /usr/local/bin/node /srv/checkout/healthcheck/app.js" $USER
end script
```

Shell script permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ec2-user ec2-user 529 Nov 23 00:16 /srv/checkout/healthcheck/healthcheck.sh
```

Shell script (healthcheck.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

API_URL="http://localhost:4567/api"

echo `date`

status_code=`curl -s -o /dev/null -I -w "%{http_code}" $API_URL`
if [ 200 -ne $status_code ]; then
  echo "healthcheck.sh: api not running, restarting service!"
  stop api
  start api
fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add path to start/stop command to your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=$PATH:/sbin/
```

or your full path to start and stop commands:

```
/sbin/stop api
```

you can check path to them using whereis:

```
$ whereis start
/sbin/start
```

Answer (score 3):

Answer found in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337854/shell-script-doesnt-execute-from-cron-job?rq=1)!

Basically the cron jobs operate in a limited environment, so in 'start [service]', the start command is not found!

Modifying the script to look like so makes it work:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH="/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/opt/usr/bin:/opt/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin"
...
```