# setuid on an executable doesn't seem to work

Tags: linux, process, c, setuid

I wrote a small C utility called `killSPR` to kill the following processes on my RHEL box. The idea is for anyone who logs into this linux box to be able to use this utility to kill the below mentioned processes (which doesn't work - explained below).

```
cadmn@rhel /tmp > ps -eaf | grep -v grep | grep " SPR "  
cadmn    5822  5821 99 17:19 ?        00:33:13 SPR 4 cadmn  
cadmn   10466 10465 99 17:25 ?        00:26:34 SPR 4 cadmn  
cadmn   13431 13430 99 17:32 ?        00:19:55 SPR 4 cadmn  
cadmn   17320 17319 99 17:39 ?        00:13:04 SPR 4 cadmn  
cadmn   20589 20588 99 16:50 ?        01:01:30 SPR 4 cadmn  
cadmn   22084 22083 99 17:45 ?        00:06:34 SPR 4 cadmn  
cadmn@rhel /tmp >
```

This utility is owned by the user `cadmn` (under which these processes run) and has the setuid flag set on it (shown below).

```
cadmn@rhel /tmp > ls -l killSPR  
-rwsr-xr-x 1 cadmn cusers 9925 Dec 17 17:51 killSPR  
cadmn@rhel /tmp >
```

The C code is given below:

```
/*  
 * Program Name: killSPR.c  
 * Description: A simple program that kills all SPR processes that  
 * run as user cadmn  
 */  
#include <stdio.h>  
int main()  
{  
    char *input;  
    printf("Before you proceed, find out under which ID I'm running. Hit enter when you are done...");  
    fgets(input, 2, stdin);  

    const char *killCmd = "kill -9 $(ps -eaf | grep -v grep | grep \" SPR \" | awk '{print $2}')";  
    system(killCmd);  
    return 0;  
}
```

A user (`pmn`) different from `cadmn` tries to kill the above-mentioned processes with this utility and fails (shown below):

```
pmn@rhel /tmp > ./killSPR  
Before you proceed, find out under which ID I'm running. Hit enter when you are done...  
sh: line 0: kill: (5822) - Operation not permitted  
sh: line 0: kill: (10466) - Operation not permitted  
sh: line 0: kill: (13431) - Operation not permitted  
sh: line 0: kill: (17320) - Operation not permitted  
sh: line 0: kill: (20589) - Operation not permitted  
sh: line 0: kill: (22084) - Operation not permitted  
pmn@rhel /tmp >
```

While the user waits to hit enter above, the process `killSPR` is inspected and is seen to be running as the user `cadmn` (shown below) despite which killSPR is unable to terminate the processes.

```
cadmn@rhel /tmp > ps -eaf | grep -v grep | grep killSPR  
cadmn   24851 22918  0 17:51 pts/36   00:00:00 ./killSPR  
cadmn@rhel /tmp >
```

BTW, none of the main partitions have any `nosuid` on them

```
pmn@rhel /tmp > mount | grep nosuid
pmn@rhel /tmp >
```

The setuid flag on the executable doesn't seem to have the desired effect. What am I missing here? Have I misunderstood how setuid works?

Comment: is there a reason this couldn't just be a shell script with `777` permissions instead of a compiled binary?

Comment: @txtechhelp - A shell script with perms 777 won't work. Here's why -  
  
If the user `pmn` invoked this script, the ensuing process would run as user `pmn` who doesn't have privileges to kill the processes that are run as user `cadmn` (unless you are the root, you cannot kill processes that are run by others).  
  
BTW, setting setuid flag on scripts won't work either: setuid on scripts that are written in one of the shell languages are ignored by the system as a safety feature. Hence the need for this to be a compiled program. 
  
Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I understand user rights and restrictions of Linux/Unix systems, I'm asking why you're trying to do this through a C program (which has the same limitations if run as a separate user in a separate login) given the code you've posted .. you're simply calling a system command from a C program, which has the same effect as calling the same command (`kill` in your program) through a shell script. Instead what it sounds like you're doing is wanting to give 'service like control' to a particular program to non-root users...if that's correct please rephrase your question

Comment: Yes, I wanted to give normal users the privileges to kill any "`SPR`" process running as user `cadmn`. Anyway, @Grzegorz suggested using exec instead of system which apparently drops the setuid effect. I'll try this out and reply back.

Comment: How is the SPR program started, by another user manually, automagically, through a startup script? .. User rights on Linux apply to ALL applications being run (it does not matter if they are in a shell script or C/C++/Java program), if a user does not have rights to do a certain action, there is no way (aside from a privilege escalation bug/attack) for that user to do that action. A 'service' or daemon gives a user the ability to 'control' it (to an extent) even though it doesn't have user rights to do so (again, to an extent...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First and foremost, `setuid bit` simply allows a script to set the `uid`. The script still needs to call `setuid()` or `setreuid()` to run in the the `real uid` or `effective uid` respectively. Without calling `setuid()` or `setreuid()`, the script will still run as the user who invoked the script.

Avoid `system` and `exec` as they drop privileges for security reason. You can use `kill()` to kill the processes.

Check These out.

http://linux.die.net/man/2/setuid

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setreuid.2.html

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html

Comment: Thank you. setreuid did the trick (though, setuid did not work). Nonetheless, the behavior is not consistent and here's why: The exact scenario, that had failed to work on the RHEL box, worked without setuid or setreuid on Mint XFCE 15 that runs as a VM on my home PC!

Comment: The difference between `setuid()` and `setreuid()` is the ownership of the file. For files using `setuid()`, it has to be owned by `root` and `setid bit`. In the code `setuid()` can then switch to any `uid` including `root`. In your case you want to `setuid()` to `cadmn`. Should you want the file to be owned by `cadmn`, `setuid()` will not work but `setreuid()` will. This is probably what you did. The man page for `setuid()` and `setreuid()` discussed this difference.

Answer (score 4):

You should replace your `system` call with `exec` call. Manual for `system` say's it drops privileges when run from suid program.

The reason is explained in `man system`:

> Do  not  use  system()  from a program with set-user-ID or set-group-ID
>          privileges, because strange values for some environment variables might
>          be  used  to subvert system integrity.  Use the exec(3) family of func‐
>          tions instead, but not execlp(3) or execvp(3).  system() will  not,  in
>          fact,  work  properly  from  programs  with set-user-ID or set-group-ID
>          privileges on systems on which /bin/sh is bash version 2, since bash  2
>          drops  privileges  on startup.  (Debian uses a modified bash which does
>          not do this when invoked as sh.)

If you replace `system` with `exec` you will need to be able to use shell syntax unless you call `/bin/sh -c <shell command>`, this is what is `system` actually doing.

Comment: Oh, I see. Let me try this and get back to you.

Comment: `exec` has the same user restrictions as `system` .. in other words, if `userX` does not have permissions to read/write/execute anything in folder `/blahsy/blah` then a C call to `system/exec('ls -l /blahsy/blah')` would give an operation not permitted error because `userX` does not have permission to that folder .. if you did this instead though `system('sudo ls -l /blahsy/blah')`, it might be a different story

Comment: Hmm, then it looks like I've misunderstood the powers of setuid. Can you give me a scenario where I can use setuid?

Comment: @pmn No, you didn't misunderstood the powers of setuid, it's just the shell that drops privileges for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link on making a shell script a daemon:

[Best way to make a shell script daemon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430330/best-way-to-make-a-shell-script-daemon)

You might also want to google some ['linux script to service'](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=how+to+make+a+shell+script+a+service+in+linux), I [found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64646/create-a-service-in-linux-using-shell-script) [a couple](http://z0ltan.wordpress.com/2013/05/05/creating-a-service-and-a-service-watchdog-using-simple-shell-scripts-in-linux/) [of links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521774/starting-a-service-upstart-from-a-shell-script-from-a-cron-job) on this subject.

The idea is that you wrap a shell script that has some basic stuff in it that allows a user to control a program run as another user by calling a 'service' type script instead. For example, you could wrap up `/usr/var/myservice/SPRkiller` as a 'service' script that could then just be called as such from any user: `service SPRkiller start`, then `SPRkiller` would run, kill the appropriate services (assuming the SPR 'program' is run as a non-root user).

This is what it sounds like you are trying to achieve. Running a program (shell script/C program/whatever) carries the same user restrictions on it no matter what (except for escalation bugs/hacks).

On a side note, you seem to have a slight misunderstanding of user rights on Linux/Unix as well as what certain commands and functions do. If a user does not have permissions to do a certain action (like `kill` the process of another user), then calling `setuid` on the program you want to `kill` (or on `kill` itself) will have no effect because the user does not have permission to another users 'space' without super user rights. So even if you're in a shell script or a C program and called the same `system` command, you will get the same effect.

http://www.linux.com/learn/ is a great resource, and here's a link for [file permissions](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions)

hope that helps