# Using SUID in Alpine Docker Image

Tags: bash, docker, alpine-linux

I am trying to run some scripts as different users in Alpine Docker image. While logged in as `devuser` I want run `setup.sh` as `root` and `app.sh` as `appuser`. Since I have read that you can't use the SUID on script files I have a couple C programs, `setup` and `app`, that call the scripts. I can run `setup` as `root` but can't run `app` as `appuser`.

Here is the content of the directories. Notice that app and setup have the SUID bit set on the programs. I tried setting the SUID on the scripts but that didn't work.

```
/opt/app $ ls -l
total 24552
-r-sr-xr-x    1 appuser  appgroup     10632 Jun 27 12:59 app
-r--------    1 appuser  appgroup  25101769 Jun 27 12:59 app.jar
-r-xr-xr--    1 appuser  appgroup       327 Jun 27 12:59 app.sh
-r--------    1 appuser  appgroup       316 Jun 27 12:59 application.yml
-r-sr-xr-x    1 root     root         10632 Jun 27 12:59 setup
-r-xr-xr--    1 root     root           152 Jun 27 12:59 setup.sh
```

I am running as `devuser`.

```
/opt/app $ whoami
devuser
```

I can run `setup` successfully. It is owned by `root` and runs as `root`.

```
/opt/app $ ./setup
Running As: root:appgroup
```

I try running `app` and it does not change to the owner.

```
/opt/app $ ./app
Running As: devuser:appgroup
Error: Unable to access jarfile app.jar
```

Here is the source for `setup.sh`.

```
/opt/app $ cat setup.sh
#!/bin/ash

echo "Running As: $(whoami):$(id -gn)"
```

Here is the source for `app.sh`.

```
/opt/app $ cat app.sh
#!/bin/ash

echo "Running As: $(whoami):$(id -gn)"

java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar app.jar $SPRING_OPTS
```

Here are the two users.

```
/opt/app $ id devuser
uid=701(devuser) gid=700(appgroup) groups=700(appgroup),700(appgroup)

/opt/app $ id appuser
uid=700(appuser) gid=700(appgroup) groups=700(appgroup),700(appgroup)
```

Here is the source for `setup.c`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    setuid(0);
    system("./setup.sh");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the source for `app.c`. I had tried `setuid(0)` too but that did not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    setuid(700);
    system("./app.sh");
    return 0;
}
```

And finally my dirty laundry; the Docker build. I have tried setting up `adduser` as a system user and a non-system user.

```
RUN    addgroup -g 700 appgroup \
    && adduser -G appgroup -D -u 700 -S -H -s /bin/sh appuser \
    && adduser -G appgroup -D -u 701 -s /bin/sh devuser

RUN    sh -c 'touch app.jar' \
    && chown appuser:appgroup *.jar  \
    && chown appuser:appgroup *.yml  \
    && chown appuser:appgroup app.sh  \
    && chown appuser:appgroup app \
#    && chmod -R 750 . \
    && chmod u+x,g+x,o-x *.sh \
    && chmod 4555 setup \
    && chmod 4555 app \
    && chmod 400 *.yml \
    && chmod 400 *.jar \
    && chmod -R -w .

USER devuser
# USER appuser
```

Thanks for any help,
Wes.

Answer (score 2):

If you change `setuid()` to `setreuid()` in `app.c` it will work.

See this answer and comments for reason: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20687988

---

However, the way you describe is non-standard. It sounds hacky to have SUID binaries that call shell scripts.

Here's a way to do it using the Alpine standard [su-exec](https://github.com/ncopa/su-exec):

app.sh

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "Running As: $(whoami):$(id -gn)"

java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar app.jar $SPRING_OPTS
```

setup.sh

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "Running As: $(whoami):$(id -gn)"

exec su-exec appuser:appgroup ./app.sh
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --no-cache su-exec

RUN    addgroup -g 700 appgroup \
    && adduser -G appgroup -D -u 700 -S -H -s /bin/sh appuser

COPY * ./

RUN chmod 0755 *.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./setup.sh"]
```

Much simpler, and probably much safer as well.